# how to know video format or type

Tags: android

i am getting list of video files from web services and playing in Videoview . Some video getting played .for example mp4. While some video are not for example .mov file.So I want to check the format of video so that i can handle in error listner in android. My question is how to know format another question-I am playing the video in videoview and doing manually streaming. I am buffering some amount and then playing the video simulataneously. video is getting played but after some time it raising warning like media cannot be played .I think that because of unavailibilty of media in file it saying like that because when total amount of video is present in file then it playing total video without warning . My 2 question is- what is your opinion .what is the reason for this .how can i correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent=anyPlayer(urlstring);
startactivity(intent);



public static Intent anyPlayer(String DestAddr)
{
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(DestAddr.toString());
  Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
  i.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
  return i; 
}
```

Comment: you need to call anyplayer and then start acivity